# Regex not working for empty string - Swift

Tags: regex, swift

My function should handle every regex and return a true or false. It's working good... still now

```
func test(_ input: String) -> Bool {

let pattern = ".{7}" //allow exactly 7 numbers
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [NSRegularExpression.Options.caseInsensitive])


let leftover = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: input, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, input.characters.count), withTemplate: "")

 if leftover.isEmpty {
    return true
 }
 return false
}


print(test("123456")) //false
print(test("1234567")) //true
print(test("12345678")) //false
print(test("")) //true - I expect false
```

So I understand why `test("")` is false. But how can I fix my regex that it return false?
Sometimes I use the regex `.*` My function should handle this one, too. So I can't make a check like this

`if input.isEmpty {
   return false 
 }`

Comment: I'd go by adding "^" and "$" (If I remember correclty my regex) to your regex to says that is needs to be used from start to end of the string, and I'd call `numberOfMatchesInString:options:range:` instead.

Comment: Only changing the regex doesn't work. I will try numberOfMatchesInString:options:range

Comment: Of course, only one of the options won't work, I say "and". So `let pattern = "^.{7}$" //allow exactly 7 numbers; let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [.caseInsensitive]); let numberOfOccurences = regex.numberOfMatches(in: input, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, input.characters.count)); return (numberOfOccurences != 0)` does the trick.

Comment: thanks a lot! It does work. Hmm I don't know: Do you want post this as answer? When not I will post it. But I don't want to steal reputation ;)

Comment: `".{7}"` matches 7 (arbitrary) characters. For 7 digits, use `"\\d{7}"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `input` is the empty string then `leftover` will be the empty string
as well, and therefore your function returns `true`. Another case where
your approach fails is

```
print(test("12345671234567")) // true (expected: false)
```

An alternative is to use the `range(of:)` method of `String` with the `.regularExpression` option. Then check if the matched range is the entire string.

In order to match 7 *digits* (and not 7 arbitrary characters), the
pattern should be `\d{7}`.

```
func test(_ input: String) -> Bool {

    let pattern = "\\d{7}"
    return input.range(of: pattern, options: [.regularExpression, .caseInsensitive])
           == input.startIndex..<input.endIndex
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution is to specify that your regex has to match the entire string to be valid, so you can do this by adding `^` and `$` at your regex to ensure the start and the end of the string.

```
let pattern = "^.{7}$" //allow exactly 7 numbers 
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [.caseInsensitive])
let numberOfOccurences = regex.numberOfMatches(in: input, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, input.utf16.count))
return (numberOfOccurences != 0)
```

In theory, we should be checking if `numberOfOccurences` is truly equal to 1 to return true, but checking the start and the end should give you only one or zero match.

Comment: Note that it should be `input.utf16.count`: NSRange counts the characters (unichar)  in an NSString.